# why the python proxy repo could not found the python library

Tags: python, nexus

I have configure a python proxy repo using nexus OSS 3.51.0-01, the python url is https://pypi.org/simple/, then on the local machine, I use this command to test the repo:

```
~/source/visa on  develop! ⌚ 21:26:50
$  pip3 install --trusted-host 192.168.50.90 -i http://192.168.50.90:8092/repository/pypi-proxy/simple flask                                         ‹ruby-2.7.2›
Looking in indexes: http://192.168.50.90:8092/repository/pypi-proxy/simple
User for 192.168.50.90:8092: admin
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask
```

Am I missing something? this is the configuration look like:

[image]